# Get holiday periods dynamically based on period rules

Tags: sql, sql-server

Each employee has a holiday policy. This holiday policy let me know the following:

- Depending on how many working years, then the holiday period could change
- Depending on how many working years, is the max allowed days per period

So, for example:

- The employee join the company on 10/10/2011
- The first working year (10/10/2012) the employee has 6 holiday days to use. But **ONLY** for the first year this days must be used from 10/10/2012 to 12/31/2012.

So the rule is:

- 1 Working Year - Period Start: Employee JoinDate (**JODA**) of that year to End of Year.
- For all the next years the rule is: >1 Working Year - Period Start: 1/1/Year to 12/31/Year.

This rules are in a table with the following schema:

[image]

**0 Year means ALL YEARS**

I used a `varchar(4)` datatype for the `startperiod` and `endperiod` columns

The maximum allowed days per working years are in the following table:

[image]

So the desired result that I need is something like this:

[image]

The first row, the period starts according the rule (where working year = 1), for the rest of the rows the periods start on the first day of year and ends on the last day of year.

I have create a SQL Fiddle with the same columns and the data.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/29681

My problem is that I can't figure it out how can I get all periods in one `SELECT` **without** using a `CURSOR`.

I appreciate any help and advice on how to do it. Doesn't seem to be a simple task.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL Fiddle:   You used JODA for both year 1 & 0.  You should be able to achieve your desired result using the workingyear_days table as the main table of your query (to get one row per year), and join to the other tables as needed for the other columns.

Comment: I just fix the SQL Fiddle you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Start by joining to a table of numbers, so that you get a row per year per employee.

```
SELECT * --change this
FROM dbo.hd_employee e
JOIN 
dbo.nums n 
   ON n.num <= datediff(year, hd.joindate, getdate()) + 1
LEFT JOIN dbo.hd_workingyear_days wyd
    ON wyd.year = n.num
LEFT JOIN dbo.hd_workingyear_days wyd0
    ON wyd.year IS NULL
    AND wyd0.year = 0
```

Now you can easily apply your logic, because you have the year number, and you can calculate the start of the year, and compare it as you need, and so on. Use `ISNULL(wyd.alloweddays, wyd0.alloweddays)` to allow for your 'default'.

Comment: What does dbo.nums means?

Comment: A table of numbers. Such as: `create table dbo.nums (num int primary key); insert dbo.nums select row_number() over (order by (select 1)) from sys.all_columns;`

Answer (score 0):

You can try as below to get your desired output in single query...

```
Select 
subqry2.employeeid,
Subqry2.startdt,
Subqry2.enddt,
Subqry2.workingYears,
Subqry2.alloweddays,
Subqry2.daysused,
(Subqry2.alloweddays-Subqry2.daysused) as remaining
from
(
select 
subqry1.employeeid,
subqry1.startdt,
subqry1.enddt,
subqry1.workingYears,
subqry1.alloweddays,
(select COUNT(1) from 
   hd_employee_holiday subqry 
   where subqry.employeeid = subqry1.employeeid 
   and subqry.date between subqry1.startdt and subqry1.enddt 
) as daysUsed
from
(
select 
Q1.employeeid,
 -- without using the rule table
 -- Case when Q2.number <= 1 then dateadd(yy,Q2.number,Q1.joindate) else dateadd(yy, datediff(yy,0,dateadd(yy,q2.number,q1.joindate)),0) end StartDt,
 -- DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,dateadd(yy,q2.number+1,q1.joindate) + 1), -1) EndDt,
 -- using rule table
(select case when startperiod='JODA' then dateadd(yy,q2.number,Q1.joindate) 
         else dateadd(yy,Q2.number,cast(cast(year(Q1.joindate) as varchar) + startperiod as DATE)) end 
 from hd_workingyear_rule Q5 where Q5.year = (case when Q2.number != 1 then 0 else Q2.number end) 
) StartDt,
(select dateadd(yy,Q2.number,cast(cast(year(Q1.joindate) as varchar) + endperiod as DATE)) 
 from hd_workingyear_rule Q5 where Q5.year = (case when Q2.number != 1 then 0 else Q2.number end) 
) EndDt,
Q2.number WorkingYears,
Q3.alloweddays,
Q1.years,
Q2.number 
from
(select employeeid,joindate,datediff(year,joindate,getdate())+1 as years  from hd_employee) Q1
join master..spt_values Q2 on Q2.type = 'P' and Q2.number < Q1.years
join hd_workingyear_days Q3 on (Q2.number) = Q3.year
) subqry1
) Subqry2
```

Output of the above query using your input tables and data is as below

```
empid   startdt     enddt   WY  DA  DU  DR
1   2012-10-10  2012-12-31  1   6   3   3
1   2013-01-01  2013-12-31  2   8   2   6
1   2014-01-01  2014-12-31  3   9   4   5
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a data model that minimizes redundancy to the detriment of complexity.  That being said, we don't always get to change the data models.

Here is a solution to your question, which uses a CTE wrapped in a function to generate the necessary tabular data.

[SQL Fiddle Solution](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0a4e9/3/0)

I noticed I read the requirement differently that you and others implemented it.  If it turns out I'm wrong, then this will give you the results as you described.

[SQL Fiddle Alternate Solution](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0178b/1/0)